# I don't want to cache my account in .git/config

Tags: git, server

How can I set up git to request account and password each time we working with git on my server?
I don't want to git cache any account or password of ours team member
thanks a lot!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: we are using centos 6.5 for ours server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `git config --list --show-origin` in your repo to see where is your `credential.helper`

If `credential.helper` in `.git/config`,  run:

```
git config --local --unset credential.helper
```

If `credential.helper` in `/Users/<name>/.gitconfig`,  run:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

If it's in other place like `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig`, run:

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Or if you don't want to remember password at all, in all of your repos on that server, `unset` all:

```
git config --local --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache), you can change the cache timeout by using the following command:

`git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'`

You can change the timeout to `1` instead, only caching for one second (`0` would, by convention, likely set the timeout to never expire, but I don't see that documented).